# EntityManager Update without find

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

It seems the standard way of doing on update using the entity manager is something like:

```
Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1); 
em.getTransaction().begin();
employee.setNickname("Joe the Plumber");
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this without doing the find..

the equivalent of

```
UPDATE Employees
SET nickname="Joe the Plumber"
WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQPL Update Query to update entity without using the primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400538/jqpl-update-query-to-update-entity-without-using-the-primary-key)

Comment: @kostja: That one seems different to me. That question is about *not* using the primary key in a JPQL update; this question is about *yes* using the primary key in a *non*-JPQL update.

Comment: It's technically identical. Id is just an attribute like any other for a bulk update. Why do you think that is is non-JPQL?

Comment: Does any one know why JPA does not support it? It seems inefficient to read and then update when I can just update... I prefer the OO way to doing it...

Comment: Doesn't support what? kostja pointed out a bulk update JPQL statement which allows you to update objects without the retrieval.