# Pros and Cons of updating entity using with EntityManager and JPQL update query

Tags: jpa, jpql, entitymanager

When I want to update entity, there is two approach

(1) First Approach (using with EntityManager)

```
EntityManager em = ....
Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1);
employee.setName("Updated Name");
em.merge(employee);
```

(2) Second Approach (using JPQL update query)

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Update Employee e SET e.name = :name WHERE e.id = :id");
query.setParameter("name", "Updated Name");
query.setParameter("id", 1);
query.executeUpdate();
```

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches from different perspective?

Comment: One caters for objects in-memory + datastore (and cascading of operations where required) and the other just does the datastore (with no cascading). All in the JPA spec and any decent JPA docs.

Comment: how about for optimistic lock process (@Version)?

Comment: I found useful suggestion of @kostja from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400538/jqpl-update-query-to-update-entity-without-using-the-primary-key